# ECMAScript 5: Why are some property attributes inherited while others are not?

Tags: javascript, properties, attributes, prototypal-inheritance

It appears that ECMAScript 5 property attributes are inherited while others are not. Based on a simple experiment in Google Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, it seems that `enumerable` and `writable` are inherited from prototypes, but `configurable` is not. Consider when `a` is the prototype of `b`, and `a` defines property `x` (but `b` does not). If `x` is not writable, then `b` cannot override the value of `x` with `=`, which would, if allowed, only change `b`'s `x`, and not `a`'s (which is the `x` marked as non-writable). However, even if `x` is neither configurable nor writable, `b` may override the value of `x` with `Object.defineProperty(b, 'x', ...)` (which would fail for `a`: `Object.defineProperty(a, 'x', ...)`, because `a`'s `x' is not configurable).

I don't see anything in the [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) that explains this (perhaps it's there, but I can't find it). Is this inconsistent behaviour intended?

Test output (answers "do `a`'s and `b`'s property attribute behave the same way?):

```js
Object {enumerable: true, configurable: false, writable: true}
```

Code used to test:

```js
function isEnumerable(p, o) {
  for (var key in o) {
    if (key === p) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

function isConfigurable(p, d, o) {
  try {
    Object.defineProperty(o, p, d);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

function isWritable(p, v, o) {
  if (o[p] === v) {
    throw 'Error: isWritable will not work with identical value';
  }
  o[p] = v;
  return o[p] === v;
}

function inheritedAttributes(
    parentGenerator,
    propertyName,
    differentDescriptor,
    differentValue) {
  var parent, child, rtn = {};
  var fns = {
    'enumerable': isEnumerable.bind(this, propertyName),
    'configurable': isConfigurable.bind(
        this,
        propertyName,
        differentDescriptor),
    'writable': isWritable.bind(this, propertyName, differentValue)
  };

  for (var key in fns) {
    parent = parentGenerator();
    child = Object.create(parent);
    rtn[key] = fns[key](parent) === fns[key](child);
  }
  return rtn;
}

var propertyName = 'x';
var starterProperties = {};
starterProperties[propertyName] = {
  'writable': false,
  'configurable': false,
  'enumerable': false,
  'value': 'foo'
};
var differentDescriptor = {

  'writable': false,
  'configurable': false,
  'enumerable': false,
  'value': 'bar'
};
var differentValue = 'baz';
var parentGenerator = function() {
  return Object.create(Object.prototype, starterProperties);
};
window.console.log(inheritedAttributes(
  parentGenerator,
  propertyName,
  differentDescriptor,
  differentValue
));
```

Comment: Take a look at `[[CanPut]]`: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.4 this function tests if you can put a value (like b.x = 1) into an object. As you can see, the prototype will be checked as well. And as far as I know, as long as an object is `[[Extensible]]`, you can always add new properties to it (for instance by using `defineProperty`).

Comment: I see. So part of the reason for this asymmetry is that assignment and enumeration depend solely on the `writable` and `enumerable` attributes, respectively, of the property (on whatever object the property is defined). However, the success of `defineProperty` depends on `[[Extensible]]` of the object in question, and the `configurable` attribute of the property on the object in question (but not its prototypes). Is that accurate?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer "why". I suspect the answer to "why" is, "because that's what the standard says". Nevertheless, here are some relevant links, excerpts, and paraphrases from the standard. Thanks to [basilikum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1258878) for pointing me in the right direction.

### Enumerable

```
for (var key in obj) { ... }
```

The [for-in statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.5) documentation states (emphasis added):

> **Enumerating the properties of an object includes enumerating
>   properties of its prototype, and the prototype of the prototype, and
>   so on, recursively**; but a property of a prototype is not enumerated if
>   it is “shadowed” because some previous object in the prototype chain
>   has a property with the same name. The values of [[Enumerable]]
>   attributes are not considered when determining if a property of a
>   prototype object is shadowed by a previous object on the prototype
>   chain.

Hence, *enumerability is inherited*.

### Writable

```
obj.x = a;
```

Property assignment invokes the internal method [[[Put]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.5), which starts by checking the return value of [[[CanPut]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4). When the property is a value, not a getter+setter, [[CanPut]] will check property attributes in the following order:

- `obj`'s `x` property's `writable` attribute
- `obj`'s `extensible` attribute
- For each prototype from `obj`'s prototype down to (but not including) `null`:

  - prototype's `extensible` attribute
  - prototype's `x` property's `writable` attribute

If any of these attributes is defined, then its value is returned. Hence, even when other attributes are missing, a non-writable property somewhere down `obj`'s prototype chain causes assignment to fail on `obj`; i.e., *writability is inherited*.

### Configurable

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'x', { 'value': a, ... });
```

`Object.defineProperty` invokes the internal method [[[DefineOwnProperty]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.9), which is rather convoluted. *In general*, this method will concern itself only with the `extensible` attribute of `obj`, and the `configurable` attribute of `obj`'s current **own** `x` property, if it exists. As such, a non-configurable property, `x`, somewhere down `obj`'s prototype chain does not influence this procedure; i.e., *configurability is **not** inherited*.